# How to get OpenERP's Document Management to save files on the file system?

Tags: odoo, dms

I'm running v7.0, and just installed the Document Management System.  Both before and after following [these instructions](http://www.baconconsult.eu/home/our-products/openerp/knowledge-management/openerp----documentation-management---configuration-in-version-70) I have been unsuccessful in locating any newly uploaded files in the file system (I deleted and re-uploaded after the change).  Also, when looking in the ir_attachments table the `store_fname` field is blank.

Anyone know how to get OpenERP to store the files in the file system on not in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the trick:  don't misspell the key name!  :/

Answer (score 1):

See Antony Lesuisse's explanation [here](http://help.openerp.com/question/529/where-are-document-attachments-stored/).

Comment: I have followed those instructions, and still my attachments are going into the database.  I'll try installing the latest code and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you've already resolved your problem, but I'll answer for those who have the same issue as you: verify that the user openerp has the rights to write in the directory that you've defined.